# How To Get Address Transaction history into Smart Contract?

Tags: address, smart-contract, script-addresses, transaction-history

If I want the smart contract to alter functionality depending of the history of the signing address, how do I access the history from within the smart contract?

Comment: Seems like supplying on-chain history to smart contracts is a prime candidate for Oracles! Already have a large supply of trusted history with all the SPOs. :)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out plutus does not support this yet (if your reading this in the future it might be out of date -> please check the timestamp).